# Higcharts uneven space between ticks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have bar chart with logarithmic y-axis. when I set min for y-axis as something close to 0 (e.g.0.1) the spaces between ticks look equal. But when I set min to  1000 according to the  requirements the chart changes its behavior and spaces between ticks get uneven. Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/2vh9h2q3/. And here is the code itself:

```
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    "chart": {
      "zoomType": "xy",
      "renderTo": $('#container')[0],
      "type": 'bar'
    },
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "subtitle": {
      "text": null
    },
    "credits": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "exporting": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "xAxis": {
      "categories": ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      "title": {
        "text": null
      },
      "labels": {
        "align": "left",
        "x": 10
      },
      "lineWidth": 0,
      "tickWidth": 0
    },
    "yAxis": {
     "type": "logarithmic",
      "min": 1000,
      "labels": {
        "formatter": function() {
          return this.value % 1000 === 0 ? this.value / 1000 + "k" : this.value;
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "text": null
      }
    },
    "tooltip": {
      "useHTML": true,
      "shadow": false
    },
    "plotOptions": {
      "bar": {
        "dataLabels": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "series": {
        "cursor": "pointer"

      }
    },
    "series": [{
      "showInLegend": false,
      "data": [4951,1200,0,0,196484,179580,0,0,0,324,87014, 11]
    }]
  });
```

I would like to leave min as 1000 and get even spaces between ticks. I tried playing with tick options but it didn't work out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tickPositions or tickPositioner if you want to manually set the positions of your ticks so their distance from each other will be the same:

```
"yAxis": {
  "type": "logarithmic",
  "min": 1000,
  "labels": {
    "formatter": function() {
      return this.value % 1000 === 0 ? this.value / 1000 + "k" : this.value;
    }
  },
  "tickPositions": [3, 4, 5, 6],
  "title": {
    "text": null
  }
},
```

Tn this case numbers inside tickPositions array are the power of 10. So for example if you have value equal to 3, you will see tick on 10^3 = 1000 value.

Here you can find an example how it can work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2vh9h2q3/1/

You need to remember that you should't use values that are smaller or equal to 0 if you want to use logarithmic axis.